# How can I get the expected parameter of any REST API?

Tags: rest

Suppose any REST api is exposed over the net which has post method and has some request body. Now how would I know what are the expected request body of that REST api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a sample/test API for this purpose. Server will return the sample of the object that you need to send in next API request body. So, call the this GET API to know what and all key need to be send.

Comment: Suppose I have exposed a REST api. Now how anyone get to know what is required RequestBody?                                                                                                                     As I have made a client for my REST api. So, while hitting the URL it returns below error:                                                                                                                                Required request body is missing:

Comment: You can use swagger (https://swagger.io/tools/open-source/getting-started/)